# Cassandra query fails for some WHERE clauses

Tags: cassandra, cql, nosql

I have a large table that looks essentially like:

```
CREATE TABLE keyspace.table(
  node bigint,
  time bigint,
  core bigint,
  set bigint,
  value1 bigint,
  value2 bigint, 
  PRIMARY KEY (node, time, core)
);
```

And a secondary index (possibly irrelevant) on column `set`.

When I do a stupidly simple query:

```
SELECT * FROM keyspace.table LIMIT 10;
```

It succeeds.

However, for *some* WHERE clauses, it fails, e.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM keyspace.table WHERE node = 12 LIMIT 10;

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/cqlsh.py", line 1297, in perform_simple_statement
    result = future.result()
  File "/usr/share/cassandra/lib/cassandra-driver-internal-only-3.0.0-6af642d.zip/cassandra-driver-3.0.0-6af642d/cassandra/cluster.py", line 3122, in result
    raise self._final_exception
Unavailable: code=1000 [Unavailable exception] message="Cannot achieve consistency level ONE" info={'required_replicas': 1, 'alive_replicas': 0, 'consistency': 'ONE'}
```

And nothing shows up in the cassandra system log.

---

**Details**

The datacenter looks like:

```
Datacenter: DC2
===============
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address        Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  192.168.64.8   234.84 GB  256          ?       478f59e1-4797-45df-81d1-77559e393e8a  RAC1
DN  192.168.64.9   217.85 GB  256          ?       84d4bfd6-054a-433e-b6d4-3eead77609ac  RAC1
DN  192.168.64.10  208.99 GB  256          ?       c6ac565e-5897-4205-9439-779becf7fafe  RAC1
UN  192.168.64.11  225.69 GB  256          ?       4a941e8f-db80-48f3-8eca-c4430b795694  RAC1
DN  192.168.64.12  208.57 GB  256          ?       34e57e18-e8b9-40d6-85e8-40a309e91b49  RAC1
DN  192.168.64.13  240.22 GB  256          ?       7a312c4f-01c0-4ed4-be7f-417b8f14f940  RAC1
DN  192.168.64.4   208.5 GB   256          ?       41a49d5c-e569-46f3-9f0e-97de43a22690  RAC1
UN  192.168.64.5   213.19 GB  256          ?       b5bfb4e3-30a2-46b5-ba41-cf1a58a7355d  RAC1
UN  192.168.64.6   212.21 GB  256          ?       9f6781ca-09b7-4923-8fa1-5b91079e2a18  RAC1
UN  192.168.64.7   235.97 GB  256          ?       5f429e7b-2e16-4796-b746-834500aeb884  RAC1
```

The keyspace:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE keyspace WITH replication = {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'DC2': '2'}  AND durable_writes = true;
```

This table is continuously ingesting 2000 rows per second using [cassandra-loader](https://github.com/brianmhess/cassandra-loader) and is fairly large. `nodetool tablestats` output (**EDIT** tombstones cleaned up):

```
Keyspace: keyspace
    Read Count: 0
    Read Latency: NaN ms.
    Write Count: 31945
    Write Latency: 7.547574268273595 ms.
    Pending Flushes: 0
        Table: table
        SSTable count: 9
        Space used (live): 15414599520
        Space used (total): 15414599520
        Space used by snapshots (total): 0
        Off heap memory used (total): 4506364
        SSTable Compression Ratio: 0.41688805047558564
        Number of keys (estimate): 251
        Memtable cell count: 0
        Memtable data size: 0
        Memtable off heap memory used: 0
        Memtable switch count: 3
        Local read count: 0
        Local read latency: NaN ms
        Local write count: 31945
        Local write latency: 8.261 ms
        Pending flushes: 0
        Bloom filter false positives: 0
        Bloom filter false ratio: 0.00000
        Bloom filter space used: 1528
        Bloom filter off heap memory used: 1456
        Index summary off heap memory used: 260
        Compression metadata off heap memory used: 4504648
        Compacted partition minimum bytes: 2300
        Compacted partition maximum bytes: 74975550
        Compacted partition mean bytes: 36544449
        Average live cells per slice (last five minutes): 1.0222222222222221
        Maximum live cells per slice (last five minutes): 2
        Average tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 1.0222222222222221
        Maximum tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 2
        Dropped Mutations: 0
```

**Output with tracing enabled**

```
cqlsh> TRACING ON;
Now Tracing is enabled
cqlsh> SELECT * FROM keyspace.table WHERE node = 1223 LIMIT 10;
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/cqlsh.py", line 1297, in perform_simple_statement
    result = future.result()
  File "/usr/share/cassandra/lib/cassandra-driver-internal-only-3.0.0-6af642d.zip/cassandra-driver-3.0.0-6af642d/cassandra/cluster.py", line 3122, in result
    raise self._final_exception
Unavailable: code=1000 [Unavailable exception] message="Cannot achieve consistency level ONE" info={'required_replicas': 1, 'alive_replicas': 0, 'consistency': 'ONE'}
```

Let me know any other details I can provide.

Comment: What is the output of `SELECT data_center FROM system.local;`?  Is it "DC2"?  Also, that is a TON of tombstones...wow.

Comment: Yes, it's "DC2" (nothing else), and yes it is a lot of tombstones. I suspected i was exceeding the `tombstone_failure_threshold` but didn't see anything in the system logs.

Comment: @Aaron I cleaned up the tombstones by decreasing the `gc_grace_seconds` temporarily, issue persists.

Comment: what secondary index index are you using ? try the query after droping the index

Comment: Can you try to run the same failing query with tracing on https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlshTracing.html

Comment: @AshrafulIslam I tried dropping the secondary index, issue persists.

Comment: @ShlomiLivne I did the same with tracing on (see output in edit) but nothing new shows up.

Comment: @spiffman can you please do the following, run nodetoll ring - that will provide the tokenownership on the cluster. Once we have that we can find the nodes that are supposed to hold the partition by checking the token associated with node=12 / node=1223. Maybe this will shed somelight on the issue.